# EXCEL - replace the same word inside worksheets, in each worksheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way with VBA in EXCEL, to replace the same word that exists inside each worksheet, with another word which will also be different for each worksheet, depending on the name of each worksheet, is it possible?

For example lets say I have 4 worksheets named A,B,C & D that contain inside multiple times the word "one".

- I want in worksheet A to rename the word "one" to "1"
- I want in worksheet B to rename the word "one" to "2"
- I want in worksheet C to rename the word "one" to "3"
- I want in worksheet D to rename the word "one" to "4"

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the replace function with a bit a directions.  `ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Replace(one,one,1)`.  And so on with the other sheets

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you're saying; however, if you need a larger area you will have to change the range.  I just set this macro to a button or you can just run it.

```
Sub Click_Me()
Sheet1.Range("A1:AA100").Replace What:="one", Replacement:="1"
Sheet2.Range("A1:AA100").Replace What:="one", Replacement:="2"
Sheet3.Range("A1:AA100").Replace What:="one", Replacement:="3"
Sheet4.Range("A1:AA100").Replace What:="one", Replacement:="4"
End Sub
```